# How to add social sharing links (FB Like, Google+) for a specific URL and not the current page

Tags: facebook, google-plus, sharing, social-media

On my website homepage I have a list of article teasers. I want to add social sharing links to the teasers. However all my attempts have resulted in the social links generating a post for the current page the user is on and not the actual page the teaser is linked to.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Facebook Like button and the Google +1 button support targeting other pages, but the techniques differ a bit.

**+1 Button**

Based on this snippet from the [+1 button docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url), you can override the default behavior of targeting the current page using either the `href` attribute or a `rel=canonical` link element in the header of your page.

> The URL that is +1'd is determined by one of three things, in this order:
>
> 1. The button's `href` attribute. For example: `<g:plusone href="http://example.com"></g:plusone>` will target http://example.com.
> 2. The page's `<link rel="canonical" ... />` tag If the +1 button's href attribute is not provided, Google will use the page's canonical
>      URL. For more information on defining the canonical URL for a page,
>      see [this help article](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139066).
> 3. The URL provided by document.location.href

There's also a [configuration tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) that you may find useful.

**Facebook Like Button**

Based on the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you can use either the `href` attribute or OpenGraph markup.

The `href` attribute works much like it does on the +1 button. Here's a like button that targets http://example.com.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com" 
  data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

The OpenGraph option requires you to add a meta element to your document's header. Here's the OpenGraph element to target http://example.com:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your examples and links were a great help. Fianlly got everything working together.

http://matttucker.onedogdevelopment.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom share buttons for each social medium. Below are the share links for popular ones.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=

https://twitter.com/share?url=

You would need to apend each "...url=" in the above with an encoded version of your custom URL. You can do this manually if you have a few articles, but if you have many, you can use:

```
encodeURIComponent(varURL)
```

And then generate the varURL by grabbing the src of your article, which could look something like:

```
varURL = $('.articleDiv').children().attr('src');
```